# When to use JobIntentService vs WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-workmanager, jobintentservice

Google recently deprecated IntentService as of: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/6f8b09029932dfd24945202017639754b00acc2e

The docs for IntentService now say:

```
 * @deprecated IntentService is subject to all the
 *   <a href="/preview/features/background.html">background execution limits</a>
 *   imposed with Android 8.0 (API level 26). Consider using {@link androidx.work.WorkManager}
 *   or {@link androidx.core.app.JobIntentService}, which uses jobs
 *   instead of services when running on Android 8.0 or higher.
```

So what are the differences between JobIntentService and WorkManager and which one is recommended under which circumstances?

Google doesn't even mention JobIntentService on this page, they only mention WorkManager: https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Since Android Oreo we cannot keep normal Services running on the background anymore, because the system will:

1-kill the service after around one minute if the app itself goes to the background after launching the service

2-throw an exception if the service was launched when the app itself is in the background

IntentService is just a subclass of the normal service, which executes all its work sequentially on a background thread and stops itself when it finishes executing all its work. But as a service, it is, as well, affected by the limitations mentioned above.

Now for the JobIntentService:

Will act as a normal IntentService on pre-Oreo Devices (because we don't have any limitations) and on Oreo+ will use jobScheduler instead to achieve similar behavior as IntentService. **It just starts the work as soon as possible**, schedules its work via
JobScheduler, and JobScheduler may elect to **postpone** that work for a bit, but its job are more likely to be differed or interrupted in low-memory situtations ,in doze mode or when they reach a time limit(~10 minutes)

With JobIntentService, doing some configurations is **impossible**,
like defining specifically under which circumstances we want our jobs to start (such as when the device is currently Charging or if we have WIFI connection), however with workmanager we **can** set these constraints.

Use WorkManager for jobs that have some **Constraints**,or  for jobs/work that are transactional **not ongoing**, or for jobs that can happen **sometime in the future**, and use JobIntentService when you want to copy the behavior of the normal IntentService on Android Oreo+ and for jobs that can be slightly delayed and might take more than 1 minute but less than 10 minutes approx.

Hope I Answered Your question.

Regards

Comment: So accessing a database, for example, then sending a notification won't need to be ongoing so Worker would be best?