# Best way get GPS Location in background for Android API level 30 and higher

Tags: android, location, intentservice, android-workmanager, jobintentservice

My application determines the speed limit by the user's location and tells the user if he has exceeded it.
Starting with Android API level 30 and higher, Google has defined IntentService as [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService) and suggests using [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html) or [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService.html) and also states that it is necessary to migrate from [Firebase JobDispatcher](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/migrating-fb) to WorkManager. I see two ways to solve this problem:

1. Start [OneTimeWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/OneTimeWorkRequest) and specify to restart this method periodically in this method while the application is running in the background.
2. Run [PeriodicWorkRequest](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest) with a minimum allowed interval of 15 minutes. In this method, run the JobIntentService method, which [runs for up to about 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59726897/1878685), but the method may not run or may be destroyed by the system before it is complete.

I'm worried about:

- potential memory leaks;
- potential problems with WorkManager or JobIntentService when going from foreground to background and vice versa
- the ability to use the MVVM pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer going with second option, it gives you more time between each rescheduling of the `Worker`.

Regarding your concerns:

- Only possible leak is misconducting location callbacks. This can be easily tracked down, you shouldn't worry too much about it.
- Scheduled `Worker` are put in the database and are executed independently of the application. Which means, user-visibility of the application has no effect. In your case, I presume you want to cancel your scheduled work once the user resumes the application, that being said you can assign a `tag` to the `Worker` and purge any scheduled or on-going once visible to the user.
- I prefer to keep `Worker`s isolated from the MVVM and just inject Use cases/interactors in the worker and do execute the use case/query the interactor. `WorkerManager` offers fine APIs to query the `Worker` status, you might need to write common ground between your previous implementation and for API >= 30. Treat the `Worker` as different execution container for your use case.